# Running total with respect to another column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, cumulative-sum

I have a table with names and dates which represent employees and dates they were in work. I would like to create running total of days they were working and if there is a break in continuity then I would like to note how long the break was before they came back to work.

Here is the actual data:

```
+------+---------------------+
| Name |        Date         |
+------+---------------------+
| Adam | 01/01/2018 00:00:00 |
| Adam | 02/01/2018 00:00:00 |
| Adam | 03/01/2018 00:00:00 |
| Adam | 15/01/2018 00:00:00 |
| Ben  | 02/01/2018 00:00:00 |
| Ben  | 03/01/2018 00:00:00 |
+------+---------------------+
```

And here is the expected results:

```
+------+---------------------+------------------+---------+
| Name |        Date         | Consecutive_days | Holiday |
+------+---------------------+------------------+---------+
| Adam | 01/01/2018 00:00:00 |                1 |       0 |
| Adam | 02/01/2018 00:00:00 |                2 |       0 |
| Adam | 03/01/2018 00:00:00 |                3 |       0 |
| Adam | 15/01/2018 00:00:00 |                1 |      12 |
| Ben  | 02/01/2018 00:00:00 |                1 |       0 |
| Ben  | 03/01/2018 00:00:00 |                2 |       0 |
+------+---------------------+------------------+---------+
```

I know I should use `SUM() OVER(ORDER BY Date)` clause once I have the differences between consecutive days but I have trouble figuring how to get those differences.

Comment: What's your expect result?

Comment: @D-Shih The expected results already posted (if I understand it correctly).

Comment: Name and Date columns are given. The other two should be determined

Comment: @BlazejKowalski Update the question for you to be clear for readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like

```
CREATE TABLE T
    ([Name] varchar(4), [Date] datetime, [Consecutive_days] int);

INSERT INTO T
    ([Name], [Date], [Consecutive_days])
VALUES
    ('Adam', '2018-01-01 00:00:00', 1),
    ('Adam', '2018-01-02 00:00:00', 2),
    ('Adam', '2018-01-03 00:00:00', 3),
    ('Adam', '2018-01-15 00:00:00', 1),
    ('Ben', '2018-01-02 00:00:00', 1),
    ('Ben', '2018-01-03 00:00:00', 2);

WITH C AS
(
SELECT *,
       LAG([Date], 1, 0) OVER(ORDER BY [Date]) L
FROM T
)
SELECT Name,
       [Date],
       Consecutive_days,
       CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(Day, L, [Date]) > 1
                 AND
                 DATEDIFF(Day, L, [Date]) < 360
                 THEN
            DATEDIFF(Day, L, [Date])
            ELSE
            0 END Holiday

FROM C
ORDER BY Name;
```

**Returns:**

```
+------+---------------------+------------------+---------+
| Name |        Date         | Consecutive_days | Holiday |
+------+---------------------+------------------+---------+
| Adam | 01/01/2018 00:00:00 |                1 |       0 |
| Adam | 02/01/2018 00:00:00 |                2 |       0 |
| Adam | 03/01/2018 00:00:00 |                3 |       0 |
| Adam | 15/01/2018 00:00:00 |                1 |      12 |
| Ben  | 02/01/2018 00:00:00 |                1 |       0 |
| Ben  | 03/01/2018 00:00:00 |                2 |       0 |
+------+---------------------+------------------+---------+
```

> create running total of days they were working and if there is a break in continuity then I would like to note how long the break was before they came back to work

You can do it like

```
SELECT Name + ' has works ' + CAST(SUM(Consecutive_days) AS VARCHAR(10))+
                ' days, and '+
                CAST(SUM(Holiday) AS VARCHAR(10))+
                ' holidays' Result
FROM T
GROUP BY Name;
```

**Returns:**

```
+----------------------------------------+
|                 Result                 |
+----------------------------------------+
| Adam has works 7 days, and 12 holidays |
| Ben has works 3 days, and 0 holidays   |
+----------------------------------------+
```

---

Updates according to your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53143447/running-total-with-respect-to-another-column-in-sql-server/53143879#comment93179773_53143447)

```
CREATE TABLE T
    ([Name] varchar(4), [Date] datetime);

INSERT INTO T
    ([Name], [Date])
VALUES
    ('Adam', '2018-01-01 00:00:00'),
    ('Adam', '2018-01-02 00:00:00'),
    ('Adam', '2018-01-03 00:00:00'),
    ('Adam', '2018-01-15 00:00:00'),
    ('Ben', '2018-01-02 00:00:00'),
    ('Ben', '2018-01-03 00:00:00');

SELECT T1.*,
       CASE WHEN
                 DATEDIFF(Day, X.[Date], T1.[Date]) > 1 THEN 1 
            ELSE
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Name)
            END Consecutive_days,
       CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(Day, X.[Date], T1.[Date]) IS NULL
                 OR
                 DATEDIFF(Day, X.[Date], T1.[Date]) = 1
                 THEN 0
                 ELSE
                 DATEDIFF(Day, X.[Date], T1.[Date])
                 END

FROM T T1 OUTER APPLY
(
SELECT TOP 1 [Date] 
FROM T T2 
WHERE T2.[Date] < T1.[Date] 
ORDER BY T2.[Date] DESC
) X;
```

**Returns:**

```
+------+---------------------+------------------+---------+
| Name |        Date         | Consecutive_days | Holiday |
+------+---------------------+------------------+---------+
| Adam | 01/01/2018 00:00:00 |                1 |       0 |
| Adam | 02/01/2018 00:00:00 |                2 |       0 |
| Adam | 03/01/2018 00:00:00 |                3 |       0 |
| Adam | 15/01/2018 00:00:00 |                1 |      12 |
| Ben  | 02/01/2018 00:00:00 |                1 |       0 |
| Ben  | 03/01/2018 00:00:00 |                2 |       0 |
+------+---------------------+------------------+---------+
```

Comment: the 'Consecutive_days' column is not given. It should be determined based on Date column

Comment: @BlazejKowalski Your question wasn't clear enogh, I'll update my answer